# GET/POST manually to website for login

Tags: php, android, html, authentication, uuid

I'm writing a few mobile apps to help students at my college access resources on their mobile devices.  I have everything functioning after a user logs in, but I still can't figure out how to reengineer the login page.  Right now, the only way to log in is to open a `webview` to the login page.  I'd like to be able to `POST` the login information directly to the page, that way I don't have to open a login `webview`.

Long story short - the login page for this resource not only passes UserID and Password, but a random UUID variable that I can't seem to figure out.  It changes with every session, and I can't find any pattern with them.  Right now, I've tried using `GET` to pull the page and extract this UUID from the source, then use `POST` to send it back along with the login information, but it fails.

Here is the login page's source (I removed the unrelated parts of the source for the sake of saving space):

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript1.1">
var clientServerDelta = (new Date()).getTime() - 1403699390279;  <!--this number changes with every load? -->
function login()
{
setQueryAsCookie();
document.cplogin.user.value=document.userid.user.value;
if ( document.cplogin.uuid )
{
    document.cplogin.uuid.value=(new Date()).getTime() - clientServerDelta;
}
document.cplogin.submit();
}
</script>
<div id="loginBox">

      <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

          <form name="userid" onSubmit="xferFocus(this); return false;">
            <tr>
              <td align="right" width="40%"><span class="style1"><b>
              <label for="user" accesskey="u">User Name</label>:</b></span></td>
              <td align="left" width="60%">
                <span class="text10">
                  <script language="JavaScript1.2">
                  document.writeln("<input class=\"textform\" type=\"text\" id=\"user\" name=\"user\" size=\"" + size + "\" tabindex=1 onFocus=\"hadFocus(true)\">");
                  </script>
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </form>
          <form name="cplogin" action="https://<website>/login" onSubmit="login(); return false;" method="post">
            <tr>
              <td align="right"><span class="style1"><b>
              <label for="pass" accesskey="p">Password</label>:</b></span></td>
              <td align="left">
                <span class="text10">
                  <script language="JavaScript1.2">
                  document.writeln("<input class=\"textform\" type=\"password\" id=\"pass\" name=\"pass\" size=\"" + size + "\" tabindex=2 onFocus=\"hadFocus(true);\">");
                  </script><input type="hidden" name="user" value=""><input type="hidden" name="uuid" value=""/> 
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </form>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I may have too many closing tags on there, but whatever, the base of the code is there; the closing tags don't mean too much.  Anyway, when I capture a `POST` stream, it's passing userid, password, and uuid to /login.  I can't seem to figure out what the heck is generating the UUID.

EDIT:

Figured it out!  SunGard's process is described in the comments here: https://www.lumdev.net/node/9994.

According to novosirj on Lumdev: "Reading the code, it very much looks like it's taking the current date in epoch milliseconds, subtracts a value that it gets from the client (which also very much looks like epoch milliseconds), and calls that clientServerDelta, and then subtracts that difference from a newly-generated date later on and gets roughly another value in epoch milliseconds (that was the part I was missing -- it does not work in seconds, but instead milliseconds)."

There's a hardcoded UUID value that will ALWAYS pass a valid session ID:  0xACA021.  I just passed that value along with my login information in a `POST`, and sure enough, I logged in.  Awesome!

Comment: Do you happen to be trying to authenticate through Ellucian Luminis?

Comment: I don't think so, @OnoSendai.  I think they use SunGard.

Comment: I do believe Ellucian is the company that was created as a merge of Sunguard Higher Education and Datatel (and therefore may use the same authentication protocol) - http://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20120326006368/en/Ellucian-Company-Announced-Datatel

Comment: Ah, then yes, @OnoSendai, they use Ellucian.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you have some options on how to implement this, but first a few reminders:

- To store authentication information on a device (user/password pair, for example) is considered a security issue, even when encrypted. In order to be useful the encryption needs to be reversible.
- Every time your mobile client authenticates via GET, it will be sending the auth pair. It may also be considered a security issue.

  That said, let's try solving your issue.

  The uuid is what ties the session together, and it is a randomly generated value. So, in theory, you should:

  - Send authentication credentials;
  - receive response and capture the uuid generated by the server.

  Afterwards, you should send the captured uuid as part of all your GET requests.

You may face some issues, though; the uuid expires after a certain period of inactivity, and the user needs to re-authenticate. You may configure the session TTL (time to live) in order to allow for a bit more leeway in this aspect.

Comment: So, I found a method using a hardcoded UUID value, and I can login successfully.  My plan now is to do exactly that - authenticate with a `POST` using user/password fields.  I don't want to store them on the device, because I don't want that liability - I'll require my users to log on every time.  But is passing them with a POST really that much of a security risk, even if the original web page is doing so as well?

Comment: Glad you've got it working! It may be if the device is somehow compromised. You're always gambling when sending persistent authentication info; that's the reason why we see so many one-time password solutions like YubiKey popping out recently.